# Jquery Hide words with the same first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have block with links, like this:

```
<div class="alphabet__links">
    <a href="#">Acorelle</a>
    <a href="#">Bentley Organic</a>
    <a href="#">BioKap</a>
    <a href="#">BioSolis</a>
    <a href="#">DeoNat</a>
    <a href="#">Dishmatic</a>
    <a href="#">Ecodoo</a>
    <a href="#">Ecover</a>
    ....
</div>
```

I need to hide all elements except the first, which begin on the same letter. As a result, should have

```
<div class="alphabet__links">
    <a href="#">Acorelle</a>
    <a href="#">Bentley Organic</a>
    <a href="#">DeoNat</a>
    <a href="#">Ecodoo</a>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted to write yourself to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
var alphabet = [];
$('.alphabet__links > a').filter(function() {
    var letter = $.trim($.text(this)).charAt(0);
    if ($.inArray(letter, alphabet) > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    alphabet.push(letter);
}).remove();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FY5eC/2/